# Enumerating table columns using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Tags: sql-server, smo

Dear data spacial lord if there's one listening to my plea,

My code looks like this,

```
string ConnectionString = "Data Source=AServerName;Initial Catalog=ADBName;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
string TableName = "ATableName";
string SchemaName = "dbo";

Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)));
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
Database db = new Database(server, connectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog);
db.Refresh();

Table _table = new Table(db, TableName, SchemaName);
_table.Refresh();
```

It passed authentication/authorization, but `_table.columns.Count` is zero, though `db.Tables.Count` has good value, so I'm wondering **how _table can be populated**.

Kindly please help, thanks.

Should there be any detail missed or any question, please do feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you hvae the `Database`, just inspect it's `.Tables` property:

```
Database db = new Database(server, connectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog);
db.Refresh();

foreach(var table in db.Tables)
{
   // do something with each table here...
   string tableName = table.Name;

   foreach(var column in table.Columns)
   {
       // do something with each column for that table
       string columnName = column.Name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, and I figured out that the code was ok, the problem was The DB I was looking at doesn't have the table, I am so so sorry.